# Is there someway to remove specific warning from an MSBuild run?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, btdf

I'm getting warning in a BTDF MSBuild run like so ...

```
EXEC : warning : If any of the assemblies were previously loaded by a Host Instance, 
  it may be necessary to restart the Host Instance for changes to take effect. 
  [C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\1.0\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj]
```

... but these are "false" warning, which just confuse things.

Is there someway to disable these and other warnings in the BTDF / MSBuild run?

I've read around and it seems that setting `IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat` to true, and using suitable regular expressions for `CustomWarningRegularExpression` and `CustomErrorRegularExpression` could be the answer to this, but I can't work out how to do it

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to pass the /warn:0 argument to BTDF, but this would supress all warnings which is probably not desirable.

The warning you are talking about is harmless (like so many other warnings that BizTalk generates during deployments).  You'd be best off educating your user(s) about what the warnings mean and when they're safe to ignore.

If you really must supress these warnings, modify the .targets file - search for the Exec statements related to BTSTask.exe (just search for the string BTSTask.exe).  Add the properties to it that you mentioned above, and rebuild your msi/project.  You'll have to construct a regular expression to supress just this warning - because you wouldn't want to supress actual warnings that have to be acted upon.